# Multiple authors with multiple affiliations in IEEETrans

Tags: ieeetran, affiliation

How to use \IEEEauthorrefmark{1} for more than one affiliation:
\IEEEauthorrefmark{1,2} doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: \IEEEauthorrefmark{1}\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}